# PHP / SQL issues when downloading a file/doc

Tags: php, mysql, database, blob

I've got some issues with a file uploaded in my database.
I upload my file (doc, img, etc.) into my database which looks that way:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pj` (
    id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    type varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    size int(11) NOT NULL,
    content mediumblob NOT NULL,
    id_demande int(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `FK_pj_id_demande` (`id_demande`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And I upload using this PHP code:

```php
if($_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
{
    $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

    $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);

    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO pj (name, type, size, content, id_demande) VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileType', '$fileSize', '$content', $queryID)";
    $resultQ =mysqli_query($con, $query);
}
```

And after to download it I use this:

```php
$sqlPJ = "SELECT name, type, size, content FROM pj WHERE id_demande = 1";
$queryPJ = $db->prepare($sqlPJ);
$queryPJ->execute();
$resultPJ = $queryPJ->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
        
foreach($resultPJ as $rowPJ){
    $size = $rowPJ['size'];
    $type = $rowPJ['type'];
    $name = $rowPJ['name'];
    header("Content-length: $size");
    header("Content-type: $type");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
    echo $rowPJ['content'];
}
```

After that my browser ask me if I want to open it with Office Word (it's a doc file) but the text in it looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

PS: used [this tutorial](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx) to help me!

Comment: I dont think it's a good practice uploading file contents to DB. You are better off creating an upload directory. The later maybe harder, but it won't give you much headache in the future.

Comment: @CholNhial I thought that using database to store files was better that just upload files in a directory because it is thinner !

Comment: no, it's not thinner. it will also add extra overhead to the database, clog up the pipes by the massive amount of data the database server has to transmit. You're better off just storing it in a directory, and save the path to database. It will allow the webserver to cache often requested documents in memory which will help.

Comment: @Tschallacka i think i will do that so ! ;) Thanks

Comment: i guess it should be decrypted, i do use the way to save jpeg and retrieve  it like ** src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($theuser->infos['user_image']).'" **

Comment: I see a UTF=8 BOM at the beginning of the file, maybe you could look into that

Answer (score 0):

In fread, change 'r' to 'rb' to get "binary" mode.  This will avoid mangling CR and LF in Windows.

For further check -- see how many bytes in the file, and in the mediumblob (using LENGTH()).  If they don't match, then something is still wrong.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I finally used the upload directory !